# How to disable arrow keys for JSliders?

Tags: java, swing, jslider, arrow-keys

I want to use my arrows keys to move something on the screen but after I click on a `JSlider` to use it and I use the arrows keys, they are moving the slider instead of the object. I can’t find any method to disable this. (After clicking on a slider, the sliding arrow changes from a black outline to a blue one {my presumption indicating that the arrows keys are “locked” onto the slider.})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `slider.setFocusable(false);`

But for a complex application, ensuring you always have control over what the arrows do may require the `KeyboardFocusManager` and `KeyEventDispatcher` APIs.  These let you divert arrow (or any) keystrokes from normal handling, so must be used carefully.

Answer (score 2):

[Key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) should provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: DYM ???, [getUIInputMap & replaceUIInputMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html), hmmmm but this is another league :-), I'd override SliderUI never tried, maybe not possible (lazyness as always broken my wings)